# Photoshop script tooltips on Mac not working

Tags: angularjs, macos, photoshop-script

I just use tooltips in my panel [Photoshop CC 2017] (over the title-tag) and when I run the panel with windows they are shown but when I try the same thing with a Mac it doesnt work. Does anyone have any tips for me? I use AngularJS but I already tried it with the regulat title-tag.

Here is one screenshot to show you what I mean:

[image]